# How to get drop item on a list - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have multiple Listbox and I want to get the droped item but I can't find it in my method.

Any ideas how or where it is ?

```
private void LB1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)

    {
        ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

" I want to get the droped item " You mean the selected items ? While change the list value by user ? 
If SO try this code

```
<ListBox Margin="10,0,0,5" Name="lb" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
    <ListBoxItem>Item 0</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

and c# code here

```
private void GetIndex0(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)
      (lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0));
  Item.Content = "The contents of the item at index 0 are: " +
      (lbi.Content.ToString()) + ".";
}
```

For more help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-get-a-listboxitem

Comment: No i want to get the dropped item from an other listbox with drag and drop
I drag an item from LB2 to LB1 and I want to know the item droppred in LB1

Comment: In order to that you need to handle mouse event for left button down for source listbox and then drop event for the destination listbox 

this link could help you 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/drag-and-drop-item-in-listbox-in-wpf/

Comment: It's move the element but don't remove the old one and the text of the moved element don't appear

Comment: I have tried the code and it works fine item that we drag to second list box removed  from first and appear in second box. 
If you dont want to removed from first box then comment this line 

((IList)dragSource.ItemsSource).Remove(data);
 to this 
// ((IList)dragSource.ItemsSource).Remove(data);

download the source and run to test 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/drag-and-drop-item-in-listbox-in-wpf/

and please accept the answer if it work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hello can you try this;

```
 <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="80,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Drop="ListBox_Drop" AllowDrop="True"  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <ListBoxItem >item1</ListBoxItem>                                                                                                          
        <ListBoxItem >item2</ListBoxItem>                                                                                                          
        <ListBoxItem >item3</ListBoxItem>                                                                                                          
        <ListBoxItem >item4</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="200,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Drop="ListBox_Drop" AllowDrop="True"/>


ListBox dragSource;

    private void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox item = (ListBox)sender;
        object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListBoxItem));
        dragSource.Items.Remove(data);
        item.Items.Add(data);
    }

    private void ListBox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox source = (ListBox)sender;
        dragSource = source;
        object item= GetDataFromListBox(dragSource, e.GetPosition(source));
        if (item != null)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(source, item, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    private static object GetDataFromListBox(ListBox source, Point point)
    {
        UIElement element = source.InputHitTest(point) as UIElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            object data = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            while (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                data = source.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(element);

                if (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                {
                    element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
                }

                if (element == source)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            if (data != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                return data;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Don't work with itemsource
The list contain data provided by Lb1.Itemsource = array

Comment: you must remove the item on data source array. After adding other listbox data source array.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of type of need to be used here the red round.

My data is in  the data element ( in green )

[image01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HzGH.jpg)